# Scheduled Batch Apex Failing Mysteriously

Tags: batch

A batch apex class which is scheduled to run daily has been failing lately.  It either shows Completed, with 0 total batches (which isn't right if it really ran as expected), or it shows Failed, with an odd error message (just "job xxx failed").  However, if I run it manually (via dev console, using same batch size) it completes as expected.

Here's the apex jobs listing:

[image]

The two recent runs showing 7 batches processed are the ones I launched manually.  All the others (starting at 6 am) are the failed scheduled runs.

<s>Interestingly, there is also a job shown from much earlier in the year, showing status = Queued.  Could that be interfering w/ the scheduled runs somehow?</s> (ignore this)

Any advice on what I should look into here?

Comment: Weirdly enough I have this exact same thing happening in my org.  I have a ticket open with Salesforce, so I'll let you know what comes of it.

Comment: @JeffBennett thanks, please do!  Do you by any chance have a stuck Queued job like I do here?

Comment: I wouldn't say "stuck" per se.  As Keith C points out, all "Queued" means is that it's scheduled and awaiting execution, which I would expect if the last job Completed or Failed.

Comment: Yeah I think that "Queued" job is a red herring.  Didn't even notice at first that it's "Scheduled Apex", not "Batch Apex".  So I think it's just representation of the active cron trigger.

Comment: @JeffBennett nothing yet from your case?  We don't have premier support, so I wasn't able to log one.

Comment: Sadly, no.  Our office's hours are opposite the work hours for the rep we were assigned, so we haven't been able to communicate super effectively.

Comment: @JeffBennett anything yet?

Comment: Nope, still failing intermittently.  Waiting on clearance from our client to grant Salesforce login access so they can investigate further.

Comment: @JeffBennett any progress on your case?

Comment: It looks like we have a query with a subquery that's taking 2 minutes to execute depending on the scope of the batch.  We're in the process of refactoring to see if we can make the query faster.  We wouldn't have gotten this information without opening up a ticket with SFDC. At this point I'd suggest you do the same.

Comment: Credit to @Enrik Hysko for suggesting this in the answers.

Comment: @JeffBennett thanks.  But I don't think that's our issue.  Because the query should take the same time to execute whether or the batch runs via scheduled job or is launched manually.  And for us the former always fails, and the latter always succeeds.  It's not intermittent like it seems to have been for many commenters here.

Answer (score 2):

The view of the screen shot you present is filtered to only show one job. I think you should look at all the jobs that are being run: you might find some correlation between the failures and runs of other jobs that are interfering with this job.

I can't offer anything on the "Failed" ones with nothing helpful in the detail... Open a case with Salesforce?

"Queued" means:

> Job is awaiting execution.

whereas "Preparing" means:

> The start method of the job has been invoked. This status might last a
>   few minutes depending on the size of the batch of records.

which suggests to me that the stuck job shouldn't be the cause of the problem in the other jobs.

I presume the cases where there was a second run in one day were manual repeats because of the zero records processed by the scheduled job?

Answer (score 1):

Try to utilize finish method and get stack trace to debug.

```
public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){
        AsyncApexJob job = [Select Id, ApexClassID, JobType, MethodName, Status, ExtendedStatus, NumberOfErrors, CompletedDate, JobItemsProcessed,
        TotalJobItems, CreatedBy.Email from AsyncApexJob where Id =:BC.getJobId()];

            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            String[] toAddresses = new String[] {'email@Company.com'};
            mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
            mail.setSubject('Daily BatchName Job Alert' + job.Status);
            mail.setPlainTextBody('Total batches processed ' + job.TotalJobItems +
           'with '+ job.NumberOfErrors + ' failures.' + '\n' + 'ErrorMessage: \n'+job.ExtendedStatus);
            Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
    }
```

Comment: can you say why you recommend this?  I would guess that it's probably not even reaching the finish method, although I don't know for sure.

Comment: if at least one batch wasn't executed we will not enter finish() method (https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/24373/46245).  Which could be in your case, you could investigate into start() method.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue on my production org, where was indicated that the job has failed but with no further info.
I have opened a ticket with Salesforce and they indicated that it was due to performance issues (one of SOQL queries on the batch class was not efficient/performative in time.

My solution was by indexing one of the fields that was used in query to make the query more efficient.

Hope this helps